# Error while including z3++.h

Tags: z3

i am using the z3 theorem prover for the first time, i installed z3 and then included z3++.h in my c++ program, but when i compile i get following errors:

```
/tmp/ccVlHDDf.o: In function `z3::context::check_error() const':
engine.cpp:(.text._ZNK2z37context11check_errorEv[z3::context::check_error() const]+0x11): undefined reference to `Z3_get_error_code'
engine.cpp:(.text._ZNK2z37context11check_errorEv[z3::context::check_error() const]+0x3c): undefined reference to `Z3_get_error_msg_ex'
/tmp/ccVlHDDf.o: In function `z3::ast::ast(z3::context&, _Z3_ast*)':
engine.cpp:(.text._ZN2z33astC2ERNS_7contextEP7_Z3_ast[_ZN2z33astC5ERNS_7contextEP7_Z3_ast]+0x43): undefined reference to `Z3_inc_ref'
/tmp/ccVlHDDf.o: In function `z3::cast_ast<z3::expr>::operator()(z3::context&, _Z3_ast*)':
```

I checked other files which were included, to see if these were defined and found

```
Z3_error_code Z3_API Z3_get_error_code(__in Z3_context c);
```

in z3_api.h. But i am not sure if its called or the function is declared. Can someone help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a linking error. What is the command-line you are using?
If you installed Z3 include files and libraries in your systems, then you should include the option `-lz3` when linking your application. If the Z3 library is not located in a standard directory, you should also use `-L<path-to-Z3-library>`.

Comment: I installed it the way it ws mentioned   on z3 website, acc. to it the libraries got installed in /usr/lib but i  cnt find the z3 flder here although i have a executable in /usr/bin

Comment: A Z3 folder will not be created. The `sudo make install` command will copy the executable to `/usr/bin`, the include files to `/usr/include`, and the library to `/usr/lib`. The prefix `/usr` can be modified when configuring Z3 (i.e., generating the Z3 makefile).